# PyCNC - Z steppers screaming

Tags: anet-a8, stepper, raspberry-pi, python, pycnc

I'm transforming my Anet A8 printer to Raspberry Pi driven using [PyCNC](https://github.com/Nikolay-Kha/PyCNC). Things seem to look promising so far apart from the Z motor doing nothing but making screaming-like sound when supposed to be moving (In `pycnc` enter command `z10`).

I was playing with the [config](https://github.com/Nikolay-Kha/PyCNC/blob/master/cnc/config.py), changed the Z related velocity and step values. Didn't see any difference.

When I start `pycnc` and enter command `g28` (all axis home) the Z needs some help... [Here is a video.](https://photos.app.goo.gl/YuCuJ44ojv6wtaqF8)

Has anyone got experience in PyCNC? Or any idea?

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to use too much acceleration (the *really* relevant thing in kinematics rather than velocity), but it seems you can only set that for all axes at the same time.

Comment: @towe Nice spot in the FW of PyCNC! For reference in Marlin default config.: `#define DEFAULT_MAX_ACCELERATION      { 3000, 3000, 100, 10000 }` for X, Y, Z and E respectively.

Comment: Thank you both. I have managed to make the Z motor work by adjusting the `STEPPER_PULSES_PER_MM_Z` to 50. I'm not sure what this exactly is. ‍♂️